# Collecting roots of different equations and create a list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, equation-solving

I solve two equations and have two solutions one by each equation. I want to create list of these roots. Could anyone please help me? Appreciate it.

m02R150 = FindRoot[P1 == 0, {E1, 0.07, 0.1}] 
m01R150 = FindRoot[P1 == 0, {E1, 0.19, 0.2}] 
{E1 -> 0.0992422} 
{E1 -> 0.195237}

What I want is to create a list:

Lm0R150 = {0.0992422, 0.195237}

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example ?

Comment: Do you want to change the output from, say,{{x->1},{x->2}} to {1,2}?

Comment: yes of course Sjoerd

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have posted an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? This is just a list? Are you just asking how to make one list out of 2 or more lists? If so, this question will be closed soon as being too localized. Unless there is more to this question than meets the eyes :)

```
eq1 = x^3 - 2 x == 0;
eq2 = x^4 + 3 x^2 - 2 == 0;
sol1 = Solve[eq1, x];
sol2 = Solve[eq2, x];
listOfAllRoots = Flatten[x /. {sol1, sol2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For many equations:

```
eq1 = x^3 - 2 x == 0;
eq2 = x^4 + 3 x^2 - 2 == 0;
eq3 = x^4 + 3 x^3 - 2 x == 0;
allSolutions = Solve[#, x] & /@ {eq1, eq2, eq3}
allRoots = Flatten[x /. allSolutions]
```

or just in one go

```
alRoots = Flatten[x /. Solve[#, x] & /@ {eq1, eq2, eq3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or using `FindRoot`

```
alRoots = x /. FindRoot[#, {x, 1}] & /@ {eq1, eq2, eq3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To select only real roots, one way:

```
alRealRoots = Select[alRoots, FreeQ[#, _Complex] &]
```

Comment: Thanks Nasser. Yeah this works fine with my code. I have several eq s , then Can I use any other method(using some iteration method.)?

Comment: As you can see, I have to use FindRoot[].Can I use this code with FindRoot instead of Solve[]. And also, can I extract only real solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nasser. One more thing,Can I extract only real solutions?

Comment: Many Thanks Nasser. In the line one you wrote for FindRoot, alRoots = x /. FindRoot[#, {x, 1}] & /@ {eq1, eq2, eq3}  Is this x, one {x,1}. With this line I am getting an error

Comment: And also, It works with your code.But, not mine. May be a mistake of my code. But, it doesn't pick all the solutions. Am I right?

Comment: Actually it is a very large code with lot of variables.

Comment: It works with Flatten. I will use that. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually, Flatten works with FindRoots. I just used after  your guidance. Thanks a lot Nasser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7787/discussion-between-thakshila-and-nasser)